# Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'WKNavigationDelegate?'

Tags: swift, xcode, webview, storyboard, wkwebview

I'm new to use webkit.

I want to give delegate my WKWebView to my view controller, but it give me error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'WKNavigationDelegate?'

My code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webKitComponent: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webKitComponent.navigationDelegate = self
    }

}
```

Comment: In short you have to have your class confirm to that protocol by doing this `class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate`, it will also prompt you to add any functions you do not have. But as a newcomer you have to know that this question is very popular, so you have to search it before asking. It is probable that you have searched it but used specific names in the search like `ViewController` and `WKNavigationDelegate`. Make sure you search an error as generic as possible, for example "Cannot assign value of type to type delegate".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swift error "cannot assign value of type 'interface controller' to type HKWorkoutSessionDelegate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662225/swift-error-cannot-assign-value-of-type-interface-controller-to-type-hkworkou)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    private func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        debugPrint("didCommit")
    }

    private func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        debugPrint("didFinish")
    }

    private func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        debugPrint("didFail")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Sh_Khan's answer; the reason for your error is that the class `ViewController` doesn't conform to the protocol `WKNavigationDelegate` out of the box.

You need to make it conform by adding the protocol and it's required methods, as Sh_Khan showed you.